# Delete lines between 2 strings in Solaris

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to delete all the line between two patterns using basic awk or sed.

`foo.txt` :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

`output.txt` :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

I am using solaris 5.10, basic awk and sed only. The number of lines between 2 patterns may vary.
Notice that the second string  must be replaced but not the first string. Notice the difference between 2 patterns is the number of dashes. What you see in `foo.txt` is exactly what I have my real file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $ awk '!f{print} /----------------------/{f=!f;if (!f)print "Deleted up to this point"}' foo.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
```

#### How it works

This script has one variable `f`.  When `f` is true (1), we are in a range of lines to be deleted. When it is false (0), we are in a range that should be printed.

By default, `f` is false when the program starts.

- `!f{print}`

  Print any line when `f` is false.
- `/----------------------/{f=!f;if (!f)print "Deleted up to this point"}`

  If we reach the divider line, marked by dashes, then invert the value of `f`.  If f is now false, then print the "deleted" message.

#### Update

The default awk on Solaris seems to have issues.  Try:

```
nawk '!f{print} /----------------------/{f=!f;if (!f)print "Deleted up to this point"}' foo.txt
```

Or,

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk '!f{print} /----------------------/{f=!f;if (!f)print "Deleted up to this point"}' foo.txt
```

Or,

```
/usr/xpg6/bin/awk '!f{print} /----------------------/{f=!f;if (!f)print "Deleted up to this point"}' foo.txt
```

#### Answer for revised question

```
$ awk ' /^---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB/{print "Deleted up to this point"; f=0; z=""; next;} /^----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB/{f=1; if(z)print substr(z,2); z=""; print;next;}  f{z=z"\n"$0;next;} END{print substr(z,2);}' foo.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
Deleted up to this point
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

Comment: syntax error, bailing out near line 1

Comment: @ayrton_senna I saw [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/158440-awk-f-works-linux-but-not-solaris.html) a recommendation that solaris users should use  `/usr/bin/nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: awk '!f{print} /----------------------/{f=!f;if (!f)print "Deleted up to this point"}' foo.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1                          May be my awk does't support your solution. I am using basic awk

Comment: @ayrton_senna Thanks.  I also see [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/need-solution-for-awk-syntax-error-near-line-1-error-4175431628/) a report that `nawk` works better than `awk` on solaris.

Comment: @ayrton_senna Also [here](http://superuser.com/a/183764/277295) is a recommendation to use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` instead of `awk` on Solaris.

Comment: Yes looks like i should probably use nawk. The man page for nawk has more options than my man page for awk in my 5.10 machine. So can you do this with nawk?

Comment: @ayrton_senna A google search showed many solaris users who experienced `awk: bailing out near line 1` were successful when they tried `nawk` or one of the other awks.  So, yes, give it a try.

Comment: @ayrton_senna Excellent!

Comment: I forgot to add last lines in my question. I modified it. Can you please answer it again? sorry and thanks

Comment: @ayrton_senna OK.  I added a solution for that to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution with awk: turn off printing after the long dashed line, turn on printing after the short dashed line.

```
awk '
    !do_not_print {print}
    $0 == "----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB" {do_not_print = 1}
    $0 == "---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB" {do_not_print = 0}
' <foo.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: @Giles can you provide the command in a single line, im getting syntax error and bailing out near line 2 error

Comment: @ayrton_senna You can remove the newlines if you want. There's no syntax error, are you sure you copy-pasted the whole command (up to the last `'`)? Did you type this in a shell? Does it help if you use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of `/usr/bin/awk`?

Comment: @Giles This i what i typed in awk '!do_not_print {print} $0 == "----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB" {do_not_print = 1} $0 == "---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB" {do_not_print = 0}' foo.txt
i am getting error

Comment: @ayrton_senna This is ok, so it must be a bug in your version of awk. Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of `/usr/bin/awk`, which is old and buggy. On Solaris, always put `/usr/xpg4/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, unless you need to run legacy scripts that are over 20 years old.

Answer (score 0):

My take. Similar to John1024's but as his is in one line, it's unreadable.
Tested on a Solaris 8 box.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk \
    -v section_start='^----------------------------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB' \
    -v delete_marker='^---------------------------------------------------  Cap in MB' \
'
    $0 ~ section_start {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
            print line[i]
        n=0
        delete line
        print
        next    
    }
    {line[++n] = $0}
    $0 ~ delete_marker {
        n=1
        delete line
        line[1] = "Deleted up to this point"
    }
    END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print line[i]}
' foo.txt
```